# Seeking assistance with building nested array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is a question that has come up a few times on here in the past but I just can't get my head around it.

This is how my output is looking at the moment:

```
0 "affiliate_hoover_plugin_options[1][radioName]:mac"

1 "checked:true"

2 "affiliate_hoover_plugin_options[2][radioName]:pc"

3 "checked:false"

4 "affiliate_hoover_plugin...ons[3][radioName]:linux"

5 "checked:false"
```

And this is how I want it to look:

```
1: "affiliate_hoover_plugin_options[1][radioName]:mac", "checked:true"

2: "affiliate_hoover_plugin_options[2][radioName]:pc", "checked:false"

3: "affiliate_hoover_plugin...ons[3][radioName]:linux", "checked:false"
```

This is how my code looks:

```
var newForm = [];

for (var i = 1; i < oldForm.length; i += 1) {

newForm.push(oldForm[i].name + ":" + oldForm[i].value);

if (oldForm[i].type === "radio") {
    newForm.push("checked" + ":" + oldForm[i].checked);
}

}

console.log(OnewForm);
```

Now I'm going to have put an extra for loop in there aren't are, which is where I'm confusing myself.

I think I just need a break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

```
var newForm = [];

for (var i = 1; i < oldForm.length; i += 1) {
    if (oldForm[i].type === "radio") {
        newForm.push( [ oldForm[i].name + ":" + oldForm[i].value, "checked:" + oldForm[i].checked ] );
    } else {
        newForm.push( [ oldForm[i].name + ":" + oldForm[i].value ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was a workable solution. It wasn't quite what I was looking for but it did the job, ta

Answer (score 0):

```
var newForm = [];

for (var i = 0; i < oldForm.length; i++) {
    var array = [];
    array.push(oldForm[i].name + ":" + oldForm[i].value);
    array.push("checked" + ":" + oldForm[i].checked);
    newForm.push(array);
}

console.log(newForm);
```

might work